# File monitoring Service in Play framework?

Tags: java, html, file-io, playframework

I am about to develop a web application using play framework in Java, but I am facing a problem in monitoring a file. I have a .txt file in my local folder, which has to be monitored continuously. Whenever any changes are made to this file certain actions are to be performed,  but still when the action is in progress the file monitoring service should not be stopped.

Is there any way in which it can be done using the play framework?

Comment: you can have a look at apache camel which offers file monitoring / directory monitoring feature : http://camel.apache.org/file2.html

Comment: Thanks Frederic ,  . . .But I already have implemented a file monitoring service in java using the Apache.commons.io.monitor.FileAlterationMonitor; But the problem is that since its a web service , I cant keep the filealterationmonitor continuously running. . I am looking forward for a way to solve that issue !

Comment: in that case can't you initialize your fileMonitor in a bootstrap job i.e. method annnotated with @OnApplicationStart http://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.2/jobs

Comment: Thanks Frederic . . I shall try the bootstrap job .

Comment: Frederic  .. I started of with the  bootstrap jobs as mentioned by you. .But the jobs is only available for Play 1.x and is not available for play 2.x .. Is there any alternatives ?